# Changing an inequality, say I have $n$ < $n^{2}$ < $ 2^{n} $

Tags: inequality

Say I have the statement
$n$ < $n^{2}$ < $ 2^{n} $

Would it then also be true that?

(I don't remember the word for this bear with me)

$2^{n}$ < $2^{n^{2}}$ < $ 2^{2^{n}} $

Comment: Yes, since $x \mapsto 2^x$ is increasing.

Answer (score 7):

Your implication is
$$
x < y \Rightarrow f(x) < f(y)
$$
Such a function $f$ is called [strictly monotonically increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_calculus_and_analysis).

In your case $f(x) = 2^x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$n< n^2<2^n \implies $$

$$n\ln(2)<n^2\ln(2)<2^n\ln(2) \implies $$

$$\ln(2^n)<\ln(2^{n^2})<\ln(2^{2^n})$$

take exponential which is strictly increasing at $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that given $x_1>x_2$

- for $f(x)$ strictly increasing $\implies f(x_1)>f(x_2)$
- for $f(x)$ strictly decreasing $\implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)$

and given $x_1\ge x_2$

- for $f(x)$ increasing $\implies f(x_1)\ge f(x_2)$
- for $f(x)$ decreasing $\implies f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$